# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'ImmutableMultiDict'

Tags: python, flask, web-deployment

This is my flask deployment code i am trying to append the all the values from request from but i am getting this error TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'ImmutableMultiDict'
how to append all the values from request from to deploy my model.
I am having trouble in converting string to list of dictionary.

```
  @app.route("/")
  @cross_origin()
  def home():
     return render_template("about.html")

 @app.route("/predict", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
 @cross_origin()
 def predict():
   if request.method == 'POST':
 
    # Date_of_Journey
    Day= request.form["DAY"]
    
    # Month
    Month=request.form["MONTH"]
   

    # Departure time
    Dept_time = request.form["DEPARTURE_TIME"]
    

    # Arrival time
    Arr_time = request.form["ARRIVAL_TIME"]
   
    
    # Scheduled time
    Sch_time=request.form["SCHEDULED_TIME"]
    
    # Taxi in
    taxi_in=request.form["TAXI_IN"] 
    
    # Taxi Out
    taxi_out=request.form["TAXI_OUT"] 
    
    # Arrival_Delay
    arr_delay=request.form["ARRIVAL_DELAY"] 
    
    # Air System Delay
    air_system=request.form["AIR_SYSTEM_DELAY"] 
    
    # Airline Delay
    airline_delay=request.form["AIRLINE_DELAY"] 
    
    #Aircraft Delay
    aircraft_delay=request.form["LATE_AIRCRAFT_DELAY"] 
    
    # Weather Delay
    weather=request.form["WEATHER_DELAY"]
    

    **result=request.form  
    pkl_file = open('cat', 'rb')
    index_dict = pickle.load(pkl_file)
    new_vector = np.zeros(len(index_dict))     
    
    try:
        new_vector[index_dict['ORIGIN_AIRPORT'+str(result['origin'])]] = 1
    except:
        pass
    try:
        new_vector[index_dict['DESTINATION_AIRPORT'+str(result['destination'])]] = 1
    except:
        pass
    try:
        new_vector[index_dict['AIRLINE'+str(result['airline'])]] = 1
    except:
        pass**
   
          
    prediction=Rf.predict([[
        Day,
        Month,
        Dept_time,
        Arr_time,
        Sch_time, taxi_in,taxi_out,arr_delay,air_system,airline_delay,aircraft_delay,weather,
        result
        
        
    ]])

    output=round(prediction[0])

     return render_template('about.html',prediction_text=" Flight delayed by {} mins".format(output))

return render_template('about.html')
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the _complete_ error traceback.

Comment: It would be nice if you could include the _complete error traceback_ and a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As far as I can understand either your `prediciton[0]` is dict instead of an float or Rf.predict tries to format the request.form at some point into a float.